# How can I display the JSON response from the API in Go?

Tags: json, go

I'm invoking a small API that gives back a JSON response with a Todo object. How can I display that in my Go web server? Right now, all that's displaying is 'Todo', which I hard-coded. How can that be replaced by the API JSON response?

Here is the code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

// Todo Structure
type Todo struct {
    userID    int
    id        int
    title     string
    completed bool
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Todo</h1>")
    })

    response, err := http.Get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    responseData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(responseData))

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to fetch the JSON document from the handler function instead of main function?  The program does print the JSON response from main.

Comment: @MuffinTop Yeah, it does. The thing is that I want it to print to the web server and display as HTML and not to the terminal as a print.

Comment: Move the code to fetch the resource from `main` to the handler function. Write `responseData` to the `http.ResponseWriter` instead of writing it to stdout.

Comment: @MuffinTop can you go a little more into depth? I'm not quite getting you. Tried what I interpret as what you meant and it still didn't work...

Comment: The code to fetch and print the resource is in the main function.  Move that code to the anonymous handler function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a function delegated to retrieve the data from the external website. Than use the `http.HandleFunc` in order to expose the method at your endpoint, here an example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

// Todo Structure
type Todo struct {
    userID    int
    id        int
    title     string
    completed bool
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, callHTTP())
    })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func callHTTP() string {
    var (
        response     *http.Response
        err          error
        responseData []byte
    )
    if response, err = http.Get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    if responseData, err = ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ret := string(responseData)
    fmt.Println(ret)
    return ret
}
```

Note:
Avoid to use the default http client in production. You can try some HTTP framework like `GIN`. I prefer `fasthttp`, here you can view some code as example: https://github.com/alessiosavi/StreamingServer